# Dynamically position the triangle of a CSS speech bubble (:before & :after classes) using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, pseudo-element

I have created a pure CSS speech bubbles with the trianglar "tip of speech" done using the "playing with the 4 borders of a zero-sized div" trick. So far so good.

But I also need to dynamically adjust the position of the triangle (in relation to the main retangular div containing the words).

Pictorial example:

http://www.designwalker.com/img/speech_bubble/speech_bubble10.jpg (Ignoring the color difference, the position of the triangle in the 1st and 2nd bubble is different).

The problem is that the triangle (and its border) is commonly done using :before and :after classes of the main bubble. And it seems in jQuery (or any javascript API) there is no (easy) way to manipulate the the CSS attributes of :before and :after classes.

Is there a solution?

I am quite sure it can be done because Facebook seems to have no trouble dynamically positioning the triangle anywhere it wants (depending on screen-fold and other factors) when the user hover on the ticker line on the right.

I have search here and found solutions of adding classes dynamically to the div but it seems to be impractical as there will then be MANY unique classes each having a different offset value. (from 0 pixel to many many pixels)

Thanks!

Andrew

P.S.:

Btw, I looked at Facebook further and it is possible that they are playing some background images sprites tricks. But I spent so much time "perfecting" my bubble using the "playing with the 4 borders of a zero-sized div" trick and I am really hesitant to re-investigate how Facebook does it, not to mention that I have to deliver the website soon..... :-(

Comment: Are thy 4 positions in your image the only four you need?  ie left, mid-left, mid-right and right?

Comment: Unfortunately, the offset needs to be adjustable down to the pixel. This is to accommodate scrolling of the window by user. The picture I showed has an horizontal offset. In the website I am building I need vertical offset.

I realize I can probably use the "insert a class" trick if there are just a few possibilities.

Comment: In the end, I side-stepped the problem. Most examples online use :before and :after to implement CSS triangles. In my situation at least, I found that the triangles I wanted work just fine by inserting the :before & :after CSS stuff into the actual html file as <div>'s. This makes the html file more cluttered and not as "elegant", but it side-stepped the issue of jQuery (or any Javascript libraries) not able to select and work on the :before & :after pseudo classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pseudo elements can't be manipulated by Javascript, since they're not exposed to the DOM proper (we used to call this the Shadow DOM, until that term came to reference ways of manipulating implicit DOM elements with Javascript).

What you can do is add classes to the containing element that will affect its position through other rules. There's a great example of [something very similar](https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss/wiki/Talk-Bubbles) (it uses `<b>` elements rather than `:before` and `:after` to achieve IE6 support — but the principle is the same, since the `<b>` element is never manipulated and infers its styles from parents) in [Stubornella](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/)'s [OOCSS](https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss) library. The [code](https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss/blob/master/plugins/talk/talk.css) is quite informative in that it shows a class on a parent element dictating how the children decorative elements should be positioned.

#### Update: painstaking explanation

Suppose the way the tips are displaying OK in and of themselves, write a separate CSS rule to define each different position for them. Here I've used `left` position on the assumption the `:after` element is creating the tip and is already absolutely positioned at the bottom. You can use whatever selectors or positioning tricks you want instead of these.

```
.bubble_left:after {
    left: 0;
}

.bubble_mid-left:after {
    left: 25%;
}

.bubble_mid-right:after {
    left: 75%;
}

.bubble_right:after {
    left: 100%;
}
```

Then all you need to do to change the position is change the 'bubble' element's class — thereby avoiding the problem of trying to affect the CSS property of the `:after` element.

Comment: The solution I described above works. Whether you're using a sprite with different background-positions or absolute positioning, you can still change that position by setting different classes. Have a look at some of those links: not only does that solution work straight out of the box, Stubbornella was actually hired _by Facebook_ to sort out their front-end! Surely the best source?!

Comment: Okay I will take a look tomorrow! It is 2am here in Asia. :-)

Thanks and nite (for me anyways).

Comment: @Andrew I edited my answer to explain the technique a bit better here rather than relying exclusively on the links to elaborate. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, it helps. But perhaps I am asking for too much? :-)

How about if I want to be able to specify the offset down to a pixel? This is to accommodate vertical scrolling of the window by the user. The picture I showed has an horizontal offset. In the website I am building I need vertical offset.

The bubble stays more or less at the middle of the screen, and the triangle has to "aim at" (track) some texts on screen. The tracked texts move as the user scrolls vertically.

Using this method it means I need MANY classes each with a different offset value?

Comment: Yes. Either you write a longer list of classes (how long? up to you!) and give an approximation of the desired position… Or if you want to make the value exact, you will need to use real elements (like the `<b></b>` in the example I linked — similar to the technique used for facebook), and use Javascript, as you initially suggested, to put that exact position on the element itself.

Comment: Great. Let me investigate the link your provided further tomorrow and hopefully can understand it and come up with a way to set the offset dynamically down to a pixel. Thanks again for your great help!

Comment: A vote up would appreciated if I helped at all, it took a lot of time trying to solve this for you! :)

Comment: I tried but as a new user I can't! I will try to gather some reputation points and come back to this ASAP, promise!